# Problem with JwtDecorator implementation in Symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, jwt

I'm trying to implement JwtDecorator in my API project in Symfony 6 but I've encountered this error, and I can't solve it.

> The definition for "App/OpenApi/JwtDecorator" has no class. If you
> intend to inject this service dynamically at runtime, please mark it
> as synthetic=true. If this is an abstract definition solely used
> by child definitions, please add abstract=true, otherwise specify a
> class to get rid of this error.

I have checked the paths, but they are ok. My file 'Users.php'. The only thing I get a warning inside JwtDecorator.php when implementing OpenApiFactoryInterface: "Use of unknown class: "ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactoryInterface'"

routes.yaml

```
authentication_token:
    path: /authentication_token
    methods: ['POST']
```

api_platform.yaml

```
    swagger:
        api_keys:
            JWT:
                name: Authorization
                type: header
```

services.yaml

```
App/OpenApi/JwtDecorator:
        decorates: 'api_platform.openapi.factory'
        arguments: ['@.inner']

security.yaml

    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            jwt: ~ 
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            json_login:
                check_path: /authentication_token
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/api/users, roles: ROLE_USER }
         - { path: ^/authentication_token, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```